# VisualSVN Server host remotely

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am currently using subversion with VisualSVN Server to manage and host my repo across my local subnet.  i.e.

`https://WIN-NU2CCXWBFDF/svn/`

How can I configure VisualSVN Server to host outside of my subnet, i.e.

`https://www.mysite.com/svn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start VisualSVN Server Manager
2. Open context menu for root node and choose Properties
3. Switch to Network property page
4. Enter "www.mysite.com" in server name edit box.

I assume that you properly configured your DNS to point www.mysite.com to your server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways, the easiest and most popular way to set it up using mod_svn which will host a SVN repo using DAV (I'm assuming you're using apache here). I use this setup myself under http://svn.mccoalition.net/ and it works wonders. You can also use [svnserv](http://www.automaticable.com/2008-06-25/how-to-host-a-subversion-repository-in-ubuntu-hardy/) as a quick way to host, although I personally prefer hosting through apache.

There's a quick guide [here](http://justinsomnia.org/2008/01/host-your-own-open-source-project-on-ubuntu-in-just-3-easy-steps/) for ubuntu, just follow step #2.

Comment: VisualSVN Server already includes mod_dav_svn and all other required components.